# Two textviews in the same line in a cardview

Tags: java, android, cardview

im doing a cardview that will include a static textview and then a textview that is loaded with the fire base example:

Name ( always static ) : Francisco ( will be loaded from database )

so i want that the "Francisco" goes in front of the name not under cause i can do it but with the Francisco under name.

````
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="35dp"
  android:elevation="16dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="275dp"
      android:background="#EBEEE8E8"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/titlePlan"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/btColor"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          app:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_light" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtlinhaa"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="   --------------------------------------------------------  "
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtpessoa"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Pessoa :"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPessoaNome"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNomePlan"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Nome :"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNomezito"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNumComprimidos"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Nº de comprimidos :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtComprimidoNum"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtHoritas"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Horas :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtTimes"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDayzitos"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dias Restantes :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDaysLeft"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDisease"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Doença :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDoenca1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="35dp"
          android:layout_height="35dp"
          android:layout_marginHorizontal="300dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp">

      </ImageView>

  </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView> ```
````

Comment: this is ho it looks https://imgur.com/a/M0944wL

Comment: If you want to keep using LinearLayout, you should have another LinearLayout within the 1st one that has the attribute ' android:orientation="horizontal" ' instead of the ' vertical ' one.

Comment: Also, if you want more flexibility on how to display your text, I would suggest your to look into ConstraintLayouts instead of LinearLayout.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 3):

Check out the horizontal LinearLayout code below to see how the `layout_weight` tag works.

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#EBEEE8E8"
      android:orientation="horizontal">


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtpessoa"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Pessoa: "
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPessoaNome"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="This is the name that you want!"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code is the most correct one to achieve what you want. With the attribute `layout_weight="1"`, with the `layout_width` or `layout_height` set to `0dp`, you'll be able to make that child of recyclerview take all the remaining space in the layout.

Comment: I removed my answer and a +1 ;)

Comment: Haha.. yours was correct one too, but it gave half the space to both, some might like that, some might like this one.

Answer (score 0):

add a linear layout and change the orientation to horizontal as below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="35dp"
  android:elevation="16dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="275dp"
      android:background="#EBEEE8E8"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/titlePlan"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="@color/btColor"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          app:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_light" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtlinhaa"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="   -------------------------------------- "
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtpessoa"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Pessoa :"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtPessoaNome"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNomePlan"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Nome :"
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNomezito"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtNumComprimidos"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Nº de comprimidos :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtComprimidoNum"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtHoritas"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Horas :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtTimes"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDayzitos"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dias Restantes :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDaysLeft"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDisease"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Doença :"
          android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtDoenca1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="35dp"
          android:layout_height="35dp"
          android:layout_marginHorizontal="300dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp">

      </ImageView>

  </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```